# Add placeholder to an existing group

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

There is a question about adding an object to an existing group but not how to add a *placeholder* (title, text...) to an existing group. Is that possible? I'm working on a template that includes animations on a group in which I want to add title and text placeholders.

Maybe the question is also answered by: how is a placeholder different from the rest? Is it possible in for instance the selection sidebar to change a normal text to a title?

Comment: It appears that it is not possible go create a group from placeholders. Is that true?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. PowerPoint doesn't allow including placeholders in groups. I don't know why, exactly, but I imagine it's because allowing this would cause all manner of problems when PPT had to deal with the placeholders on the slide master/layout being moved/changed/deleted.